# Why chart don't update?

Tags: vuejs2, datepicker, chart.js, dynamic-data

I am trying to integrate datepicker in my chart. But after selecting `dateTo` or `dateFrom` - nothing changes.
I have used construction `this.chart.update()` in watch.
I logged `this.chart.update()`, and I see following:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?
Why my chart don't update?
If put in watch just draw() - charts will be update, but `dateTo` or `dateFrom` - will be old (not that I select in datepicker).

```html
    <template>
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Прибыль/посещаемость</h3>
        <date-picker v-model="dateFrom" valueType="date"></date-picker>
        <date-picker v-model="dateTo" valueType="date"></date-picker>
        <canvas ref="mainChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import Chart from 'chart.js';
    import DatePicker from 'vue2-datepicker';
    import 'vue2-datepicker/index.css';
    
    export default {
      name: 'Analytics-test',
      components: {
        DatePicker
      },
      data: () => ({
        dateFrom: new Date('2021-11-01'),
        dateTo: new Date(),
        flagStartDate: false,
        chartData: null,
        mychart:null,
        labels: [],
        dataset: {},
        draftData: null,
        data: [],
        datacollection: [],
        clubsId: ['5c3c5e12ba86198828baa4a7', '5c3c5e20ba86198828baa4c5', '60353d6edbb58a135bf41856', '61e9995d4ec0f29dc8447f81', '61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e'],
      }),
      methods: {
        draw() {
          if (this.mychart) {
            this.mychart.destroy();
          }
          const ctx = this.$refs.mainChart;
          this.mychart = new Chart(ctx,
            {
              type: 'line',
              data: {
                labels: this.labels,
                datasets: this.datacollection
              },
              options: {
                legend: {
                  display: true,
                  position: 'bottom',
                },
                responsive: true,
                elements: {
                },
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [{
                    type: "time",
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                      display: false,
                    },
                    ticks: {
                      major: {
                        fontStyle: "bold",
                        fontColor: "#FF0000"
                      }
                    }
                  }],
    
                  yAxes: [
                    {
                      id: 'y1',
                      type: 'linear',
                      position: 'left',
                      display: false
                    },
                    {
                      id: 'y2',
                      type: 'linear',
                      position: 'right',
                      display: false
                    },
                    {
                      id: 'y3',
                      type: 'linear',
                      position: 'left',
                      display: false
                    },
                    {
                      id: 'y4',
                      type: 'linear',
                      position: 'right',
                      display: false
                    },
                    {
                      id: 'y5',
                      type: 'linear',
                      position: 'left',
                      display: false
                    },
    
                    {
                      display: false,
                      gridLines: {
                        display: false
                      },
                      scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: this.labelY
                      },
                      ticks: {
                        min: 0, 
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        stepSize: 100  
                      }
                    }]
                }
              }
    
            });
        },
        

    participantsCountClub(clubId) {
      switch (clubId) {
        case '5c3c5e12ba86198828baa4a7':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Фрунзенской", borderColor: "#3e95cd", fill: false }
        case '5c3c5e20ba86198828baa4c5':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Чернышевской", borderColor: "#8e5ea2", fill: false };
        case '60353d6edbb58a135bf41856':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Василеостровской", borderColor: "#e8c3b9", fill: false };
        case '61e9995d4ec0f29dc8447f81':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Московской", borderColor: "#3cba9f", fill: false };
        case '61e999fc4ec0f29dc844835e':
          return { label: "Тренировок на Лесной", borderColor: "#c45850", fill: false };
        default:
          return 'Неизвестный клуб';
      }
    },

    async loadTrainings(clubsId) {
      try {
        for (let clubId in clubsId) {
          clubId = clubsId[clubId]
          let dateFrom = this.dateFrom
          let dateTo = this.dateTo
          let groupBy = 'month'
          await this.$store.dispatch('loadAvgSchedule', { clubId, dateFrom, dateTo, groupBy })
          this.draftData = this.$store.state.avgShedule
          if (this.labels.length === 0) {
            this.getDatesAvgIncome()
          }
          this.flagStartDate = true
          await this.getParticipantsCount(clubId)
          this.flagStartDate = false
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    },

    async getParticipantsCount(clubId) {
      for (let item in this.draftData) {
        let positionDate = this.labels.indexOf(this.draftData[item].date.slice(0, 7))
        if (this.flagStartDate && positionDate > 0) {
          let zerroArray = await this.bindDataDates(positionDate)
          this.data = this.data.concat(zerroArray)
        }
        this.data.push(this.draftData[item].participantsCount)
        this.flagStartDate = false
      }
      this.dataset.data = this.data
      Object.assign(this.dataset, this.participantsCountClub(clubId))
      Object.assign(this.dataset, { yAxisID: 'y5', hidden: true })
      this.datacollection.push(this.dataset)
      this.data = []
      this.dataset = {}
    },


    //omitted other functions..
    
    
      },
    
      watch: {
        dateFrom() {
          console.log('dateFrom changed to', this.dateFrom),
          console.log('this.mychart', this.mychart),
          this.mychart.update()
        },
        dateTo() {
          console.log('dateTo changed to', this.dateTo)
          this.mychart.update()
        }
      },
    
      async mounted() {
        await this.loadIncomings(this.clubsId),
          await this.loadAvgIncomings(this.clubsId),
          await this.loadAvgPayments(this.clubsId),
          await this.loadAvgSchedule(this.clubsId),
          await this.loadTrainings(this.clubsId)
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.draw()
          })
      },
    }
    </script>
    
    <style>
    .container form {
      display: flex;
    }
    </style>
```

I set `dateTo` and `dateFrom` in functions(for example loadTrainings()), before it creates request to store (in store this function create axios request to API).

```js
    let dateFrom = this.dateFrom
    let dateTo = this.dateTo
    let groupBy = 'month'
    await this.$store.dispatch('loadAvgSchedule', { clubId, dateFrom, dateTo, groupBy })
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I don't see where, after datepicker sets dateFrom and dateTo, you are changing the datasets or the options of the chart in order to reflect the filter. Maybe it's enough you set min and max to the index scale, with dateFrom and dateTo

Comment: @user2057925 I added information in post about sets dateFrom and dateTo.  I have in functions, that create request to store 2 strings that reset dateTo and dateFrom

Comment: I think you are replacing the datasets.data array by " this.dataset.data = this.data". I think you could clear the array and push new values maintaining the original array. and then invoke the chart.update()

Comment: @user2057925 Thanks! It's helped me. I forget that I must rewrite data and labels to this.mychart.data

Comment: fine! Now is it working as expected?

Comment: @user2057925 Yes!